# MariaDB JSON_ARRAYAGG gives wrong result

Tags: mariadb, distinct

#### I have 2 problems in MariaDB 15.1 when using `JSON_ARRAYAGG`

---

###### 1. The brackets `[]` are omitted

###### 2. wrong result, values are duplicates or omitted

---

My database is the following:

user:

```
+----+------+
| id | name |
+----+------+
|  1 | Jhon |
|  2 | Bob  |
+----+------+
```

car:

```
+----+---------+-------------+
| id | user_id | model       |
+----+---------+-------------+
|  1 |       1 | Tesla       |
|  2 |       1 | Ferrari     |
|  3 |       2 | Lamborghini |
+----+---------+-------------+
```

phone:

```
+----+---------+----------+--------+
| id | user_id | company  | number |
+----+---------+----------+--------+
|  1 |       1 | Verzion  |      1 |
|  2 |       1 | AT&T     |      2 |
|  3 |       1 | T-Mobile |      3 |
|  4 |       2 | Sprint   |      4 |
|  5 |       1 | Sprint   |      2 |
+----+---------+----------+--------+
```

---

##### 1. The brackets `[]` are omitted

For example this query that gets users with their list of cars:

```sql
SELECT
  user.id   AS id,
  user.name AS name,
  JSON_ARRAYAGG(
    JSON_OBJECT(
      'id',    car.id,
      'model', car.model
    )
  ) AS cars
FROM user
INNER JOIN car ON user.id = car.user_id
GROUP BY user.id;
```

Result: brackets `[]` were omitted in `cars` (`JSON_ARRAYAGG` has the behavior similar to `GROUP_CONCAT`)

```
+----+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
| id | name | cars                                                      |
+----+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | Jhon | {"id": 1, "model": "Tesla"},{"id": 2, "model": "Ferrari"} |
|  2 | Bob  | {"id": 3, "model": "Lamborghini"}                         |
+----+------+-----------------------------------------------------------+
```

However when adding the filter `WHERE user.id = 1`, the brackets `[]` are not omitted:

```
+----+------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
| id | name | cars                                                        |
+----+------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | Jhon | [{"id": 1, "model": "Tesla"},{"id": 2, "model": "Ferrari"}] |
+----+------+-------------------------------------------------------------+
```

---

##### 2. Incorrect wrong result, values are duplicates or omitted

This error is strange as the following conditions must be met:

- Consult more than 2 tables
- The `DISTINCT` option must be used
- A user has at least 2 cars and at least 3 phones.

##### Duplicate values

for example, this query that gets users with their car list and their phone list:

```sql
SELECT
  user.id   AS id,
  user.name AS name,
  JSON_ARRAYAGG( DISTINCT
    JSON_OBJECT(
      'id',    car.id,
      'model', car.model
    )
  ) AS cars,
  JSON_ARRAYAGG( DISTINCT
    JSON_OBJECT(
        'id',      phone.id,
        'company', phone.company,
        'number',  phone.number
    )
  ) AS phones
FROM  user
INNER JOIN car   ON user.id =   car.user_id
INNER JOIN phone ON user.id = phone.user_id
GROUP BY user.id;
```

I will leave the output in json format and I will only leave the elements that interest.

Result: brackets `[]` were omitted and duplicate `Verizon`

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Jhon",
  "phones": // [ Opening bracket expected
    {
      "id": 5,
      "company": "Sprint",
      "number": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "company": "Verzion",
      "number": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 1,
      "company": "Verzion",
      "number": 1
    }, // Duplicate object with the DISTINCT option
    {
      "id": 2,
      "company": "AT&T",
      "number": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "company": "T-Mobile",
      "number": 3
    }
  // ] Closing bracket expected
}
```

##### Omitted values

This error occurs when omit `phone.id` is omitted in the query

```sql
SELECT
  user.id   AS id,
  user.name AS name,
  JSON_ARRAYAGG( DISTINCT
    JSON_OBJECT(
      'id',    car.id,
      'model', car.model
    )
  ) AS cars,
  JSON_ARRAYAGG( DISTINCT
    JSON_OBJECT(
        --'id',      phone.id,
        'company', phone.company,
        'number',  phone.number
    )
  ) AS phones
FROM  user
INNER JOIN car   ON user.id =   car.user_id
INNER JOIN phone ON user.id = phone.user_id
GROUP BY user.id;
```

Result: brackets `[]` were omitted and `Sprint` was omitted.

Apparently this happens because it makes an OR type between the columns of the `JSON_OBJECT`, since the `company` exists in a different row and `number` in a other different row

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Jhon",
  "phones": // [ Opening bracket expected
  //{ 
  //  "company": "Sprint",
  //  "number": 2
  //}, `Sprint` was omitted
    {
      "company": "Verzion",
      "number": 1
    },
    {
      "company": "AT&T",
      "number": 2
    },
    {
      "company": "T-Mobile",
      "number": 3
    }
  // ] Closing bracket expected
}
```

> `GROUP_CONCAT` instance of `JSON_ARRAYAGG` solves the problem of `duplicate` or `omitted` objects

However, by adding the filter `WHERE user.id = 1`, the brackets `[]` are not omitted and also the problem of `duplicate` or `omitted` objects is also solved:

```json
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Jhon",
  "phones": [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "company": "Verzion",
      "number": 1
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "company": "AT&T",
      "number": 2
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "company": "T-Mobile",
      "number": 3
    },
    {
      "id": 5,
      "company": "Sprint",
      "number": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

---

#### What am I doing wrong?

---

So far my solution is this, but I would like to use JSON_ARRAYAGG since the query is cleaner

```sql
SELECT
  CONCAT(
    '[',
    GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT   
      JSON_OBJECT(
        ...
      )
    ),
    ']'
  )
```